# How to convert a date to local date time

Tags: flutter, dart

I cannot change my string date to local date in dart.
What am i missing.
this is my date format i get: "2021-02-01T17:00:00.000Z"

```
final dateTime = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ").parse(date, true);
        var dateLocal = dateTime.toLocal();
```

Comment: What's the exact date string you're tying to parse?

Comment: 2021-02-01T17:00:00.000Z

Comment: https://prafullkumar77.medium.com/flutter-format-a-date-with-locale-using-dart-c6fa400c8a53

Comment: it cant detect the locale by the system? i have to provide which one i want like US?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `DateTime.parse` method:

```dart
String givenDate = '2021-02-01T17:00:00.000Z';
DateTime localDate = DateTime.parse(givenDate).toLocal();
```

Comment: I see it is working on dart pad but for me it isn't what can be the issue?

Comment: @nadav What's your time zone; which device are you testing this code on?

Comment: my time zone is GMT+2), i test it on pixel_3a, now i remember my emulator crushed a lot so i rebooted him. is it cause this somehow?

Comment: @nadav Can you please test it on a real device?

Comment: No but i changed the date and time in the real settings of the pixel 3 now it is working